# Is there a way to change the text alignment in Plotly Sankey diagram?

Tags: python, plotly, text-alignment, sankey-diagram, plotly-python

I am trying to change the orientation of the node label to be left of the node and in the white space for better readability, similar to how the 'C' labels are aligned.

[image]

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A2, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
      value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2]
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Sankey.html